# Загрузка превью из вставленных ссылок

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Всем привет, есть такая задача.

Есть поле в которое пользователь может вставить ссылку, вопрос в том.

> Как загружать информацию (Оглавнение Сайта) из ссылки, наподобие того
>   когда в соц сети вставляешь ссылку, они тебе показывают title сайта и
>   картинку

Через Javascript / Jquery , либо PHP

Comment: Поставить событие mouseover (onMouseOver и т.д.). В обработчике получить объект. Их объекта извлечь ссылку. Далее путь а) посмотреть готовые сервисы/решения б) загрузить и распарстить самому - т.к браузер скорее всего не даст загружать с другого сайт, то отправить ссылку на свой сервер, который загрузит, распарсит, и вернёт нужную информацию клиенту. в) отрендерить popover или что-то подобное.. Надеюсь это поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходим парсер **OpenGraph**. Это дополнительные метаданные на странице, которые используют Google+, Facebook, Slack, Twitter, Vk и другие сервисы для встраивания содержимого страниц в свои ленты.
Если немножко поискать, то можете найти готовые решения на PHP, например
https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph или https://github.com/mapkyca/php-ogp.

Про сам протокол **OpenGraph** можете подробнее почитать на этой [странице](http://ruogp.me/)

Comment: спасибо использовал библиотеку которую вы посоветовали, спарсилось, ответ принимаю и плюсую